# Using a Array of objects with $.when

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have Array of Ajax requests, the length of this Array.  When I know that they are all loaded I want to process the results

The code I'm using is

```
$.when(
    RequestArray        
).done(function(){
    this.processResults();
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas why it's not working?

When I replace RequestArray with RequestArray[0], RequestArray[1] it works perfectly.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the $.when not accept a request array. you shoudl use
`$(requestArray).each($.when(this).done(......));`

Answer (score 1):

If you pass multiple requests to `when` you're supposed to put them in separate arguments, not to pass an array of requests. So, `$.when.apply(RequestArray).done(...)`.